# How do i rewrite url based on arguments?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 pages 1 for filter where I have set the url by year make model and other details total arguments are 5 its working absolutely fine, but when someone click on details i have other page for details so url will have 1 more argument with the descriptions. but how do I set the page to read details from my other page.
here i am adding the .htaccess,

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$ filter-result.php?year=$1&maker=$2&model=$3&bodytype=$4&glasstype=$5 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$ view-glass-details.php?year=$1&maker=$2&model=$3&bodytype=$4&glasstype=$5&desc=$6 [NC,L]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. If those rules work as desired, then what do you refer to by "read details from my other page"?

Comment: I have problem in 2nd page view-glass-details.php, Actually the case is depended on arguments like if I have $5 arguments i should read filter-result.php but if i have $6 argument than it should read the view-glass-details.php but its still reading the filter-result.php.

Comment: You probably need to use `([^/]+)` instead of `(.+)`.

Comment: Thanks its working now!